# wysiwyg mindmup text editor : how to get the formatted text on server side?

Tags: text, editor, wysiwyg, server-side, server

Hello I am learning Bootstrap and would like to have a wysiwyg editor. 
I found bootstrap-wysiwyg and want to use it.

http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/

this example in website official use

```
<div id="editor">

</div>
```

not use

```
<input type="text" name="editor"> or <textarea name="editor"> </textarea>
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get formatted text on the server-side when a form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution is Submit Form by js method.

```
<div class="field" id="editor" data-placeholder="Insert your description."></div>
<input type="hidden" name="description"  id="editor_description" value="" />

<script>
    function submitform(){
      $('#editor_description').val($('#editor').html());
      $("#form").submit();
     }
</script>
```